# How to create two input text field inside UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to create UISearchbar with two input fields one for keyword and the other for location like Yelp application , how i can do something like this , please advice 
[image: this is a snapshot of my requirement]

Comment: Pls. provide snapshot of your requirement.

Comment: i added the yelp search , because  i want to do some thing similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can have two search parameters in the same UISearchbar. You will have to create your search component for that, maybe a view with two UItextField and a Search Button and you can use UITextFieldDelegates to perform the various search operations.

Refer to [Customizing Appearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html) of UISearchBar from Apple.